# How to create formula of data based on grouped data in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, formula

I'm new to CR and wondering if I create the group first. And then I create formulas, will the data shown from the formulas calculated from the grouped data or from the original data?

Update:1/22

For example,
first group by Division
and then group by Region
at last I want to calculate the percentage for each Region.

- Division 1     Period 1    Period 2

  - Region 1     20%           10%
  - Region 2     66%           50%
- Divison 1 Total 57%           16%
- Division 2     p1      p2

  - Region 1    ..
    ...

Comment: You need to add more detail to this question.  The fields name and the calculations would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

- Insert a group on the desired field
- Insert a summarized field

or

Create a formula that references the two:

```
// {@summary}
Sum({table.field_to_summarize}, {table.field_to_group})
```

Comment: what if i have two groups? how do i use it in sum function?

Comment: You should update your question to include the specifics of your requirements.